# use NET::SMTP SSL/TLS with SOCKS

Tags: perl, sockets, smtp, socks

I have some realization of bind, connect to SOCKS and connect to SMTP server through SOCKS. How i can use this connect with SSL/TLS NET::SMTP? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253360/using-socks5-proxy-with-netsmtp) not help me, because SSL handshake can't start.

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:683: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: handshake failed because socket did not became ready
```

Here realization of connect to remote server via proxy:

```
sub connect {
    my ($ip, $port, $is_ssl, $pid, $server) = @_;
    if (defined $socket) {
        my ($packed_cmd, $buffer, @data, %response);
        $packed_cmd = pack("C4Nn", 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, $ip, $port);
        $socket->send($packed_cmd);
        if (defined $socket->recv($buffer, 1024)) {
            @data = unpack("C4 L S", $buffer);
            $response{'version'} = $data[0];
            $response{'result'} = $data[1];
            $response{'reg'} = $data[2];
            $response{'type'} = $data[3];
            $response{'ip'} = $data[4];
            $response{'port'} = $data[5];
            $socket->blocking(0);
            if ($is_ssl) {
                &debug(3, $pid, "Try start SSL handshake with [$server]\n");
                IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($socket, SSL_version => 'SSLv23', SSL_ca_file => SSL_CA_FILE) or &debug(3, $pid, "Cannot start SSL handshake! $@\n") and return 0; 
                &debug(3, $pid, "SSL handshake done!\n");
            }
            # TODO: Make TLS support
            return 1;
        }
    }
    &debug(3, $pid, "Cannot connect to [$server:$port] through socks server [$socks_name:$socks_server]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Bind SOCKS

```
sub bind_socks {
    my ($pid) = @_;
    my ($method, $packed_cmd, $buffer, @data, %response);
    $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerAddr => $socks_server,
        PeerPort => $socks_port,
        Proto => 'tcp',
        Timeout  => SOCKS5_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
    ) or &debug(3, $pid, "Cannot connect to the socks server [$socks_server] $@\n") and return 0;
    &debug(3, $pid, "Connected to the socks server [$socks_name:$socks_server]\n");
    $socket->blocking(1);
    if ($socks_username && $socks_password) {
        $method = 0x02;
    } else {
        $method = 0x00;
    }
    $packed_cmd = pack("C3", 0x05, 0x01, $method);
    $socket->send($packed_cmd);
    if (defined $socket->recv($buffer, 1024)) {
        @data = unpack("C2", $buffer);
        $response{'version'} = $data[0];
        $response{'method'} = $data[1];
        if ((defined $response{'version'}) && (defined $response{'method'}) && ($response{'version'} eq 5) && ($response{'method'} eq $method)) {
            if ($method == 2) {
                $packed_cmd = pack("CC", 0x01, length($socks_username)) . $socks_username . pack("C", length($socks_password)) . $socks_password;
                $socket->send($packed_cmd);
                if (defined $socket->recv($buffer, 1024)) {
                    @data = unpack("C2", $buffer);
                    $response{'version'} = $data[0];
                    $response{'status'} = $data[1];
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            &debug(3, $pid, "Cannot authenticate on socks server [$socks_name:$socks_server]\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    &debug(3, $pid, "Cannot authenticate on socks server [$socks_name:$socks_server]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably show more code here - i.e. the part of your script that does the set up of the SOCKS connection (file descriptor etc.). Perhaps something like [`IO::Socket::Socks::Wrapper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::Socks::Wrapper) would help?

Comment: I add realization of bind socks. I already see this module, but still cannot understand, how use established connection. And i don't want change realization of socks because it's already works with IMAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904106/problems-with-smtp-via-socks/29010752) is my beta code to use SMTP via socks proxy. SSL is working correctly with all servers tested by me. With TLS still have sometimes problems, probably something not according to the RFC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with IMAP instead of SMTP this might help, but prob not what you're looking for:

```
sub login() {

  ## Connect to the IMAP server via SSL
  my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(PeerAddr => 'imap.gmail.com',PeerPort => 993);
  if(!$socket) {
    # handle
  }

  ## Build up a client attached to the SSL socket.
  ## Login is automatic as usual when we provide User and Password
  my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(Socket   => $socket,
                                   User     => $username,
                                   Password => $password,);
  if(!$imap) {
    # handle
  }

  if(!$imap->IsAuthenticated() && ...) {
    # handle
  }

  ## good to go
  my @folders = $imap->folders();
  ...
}
```

Comment: IMAP instead of SMTP? Protocols for completely different purposes.