# Problems with smtp via socks

Tags: perl, sockets, smtp, socks

Since I did not find solution to the problem description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857021/use-netsmtp-ssl-tls-with-socks), I decided to use `sysread` and `syswrite` for dialog with smtp server. Below is my test code:

```
sub test {
    my ($dbh) = @_;
    my $server = "smtp.mail.ru";
    my $ip = $server;
    $ip = inet_aton($ip);
    $ip = inet_ntoa($ip);
    $ip = &ip2long($ip);
    my $port = 465;
    my $pid = 0;
    my $is_ssl = 1;
    my $answer;
    my $user = 'my_mail@mail.ru';
    my $buff = 8192;
    if (&choose_proxy($ip, $port, $dbh, $pid)) {
        if (&connect($ip, $port, $is_ssl, $pid, $server)){
            data_read($buff);
            my $ehlo = "ehlo mydomain.com\n";
            data_send($ehlo);
            data_read($buff);
            my $auth = "auth login\n";
            data_send($auth);
            data_read($buff);
            my $smtpuser = encode_base64($user);
            my $smtppassword = encode_base64('password');
            data_send($smtpuser);
            data_read($buff);
            data_send($smtppassword);
            data_read($buff);
            my $mail = "mail from: <$user>\n";
            data_send($mail);
            data_read($buff);
            my $to = 'my_mail@mail.ru';
            $to = "rcpt to: <$to>\n";
            data_send($to);
            data_read($buff);
            my $start = "DATA\n";
            syswrite($socket, $start, length($start)); 
            data_read($buff);
            my $data = "test message\n";
            data_send($data);
            my $end .= ".\n";
            data_send($end);
            data_read($buff);
            my $quit = "quit\n";
            data_send($quit);
            data_read($buff);
            return $socket;
        }
    }
}

sub data_send {
    my $data = shift;
    if ($debug_smtp) {
        print ">> $data";
    }
    syswrite($socket, $data, length($data));
}

sub data_read {
    my $buff = shift;
    my $data;
    sleep(1);
    sysread($socket, $data, $buff);
    if ($debug_smtp) {
        print "<< $data";
    }
}
```

I had a lot of questions and errors that I can't solve.

At first, sometimes! i get:`Use of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at ...` after end of data(`data_send($end);`).

Secondly, `data_send($end)` not working on Gmail, all this code not working on GMX.

Thirdly, code `while {sysread($socket, $data, $buff);}` not work, and i use `sleep(1)`, its bad.

Finally, i received file with headers and body of message, but `syswrite` not work for variable that contains the file content.

I would be grateful for any help, thank you.

Comment: There is no error checking, no debug output is shown and your are not talking SMTP the right way. If you want to do all the SMTP stuff by hand please make yourself first familiar with how the standard works, i.e. with [RFC 2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt).

Comment: Here is only test method, i have not yet added error checking, and what debug you are saying? And what am I doing wrong according to the RFC?

Comment: "...what am I doing wrong according to the RFC" - at the minimum you are not reading the response properly. These are single-line or multi-line responses and there is no guarantee that just using sysread will get the full response. Also the response has a status code which needs to be checked. Also, syswrite is not guaranteed to write everything you gave it. And for DATA there is a special way the data need to be prepared. Also, line ends are CR LF not LF only ....

Comment: then you can tell me what to use for guaranteed delivery and receiving messages? code checking i add later. And i use `.\r\n`, result is similar

Comment: guaranteed delivery: check the length you get back from sysread and send more if the length is not reached.  receiving: read lines, check status codes, read standard how to get response back. As for CR LF vs LF - some servers don't care, others do.

Comment: ty, i will try. But `.\r\n` doesn't work on gmail, i don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my beta code, it works for most popular smtp server.

```
sub send_message {
    my ($dbh, $server, $port, $is_ssl, $user, $pass, $to, $pid) = @_;
    my $ip = $server;
    $ip = inet_aton($ip);
    $ip = inet_ntoa($ip);
    $ip = &ip2long($ip);
    my @to = @{$to};
    if (&choose_proxy($ip, $port, $dbh, $pid)) {
        if (&connect($ip, $port, $is_ssl, $pid, $server)){      
            if (data_read($pid) ne 220) { &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error) }
            greeting($socks_name, $pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            if ( $is_ssl eq 2 ) { 
                starttls($pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
                IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($socket, SSL_version => 'SSLv23', SSL_ca_file => SSL_CA_FILE, SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER) or &debug(3, $pid, "Cannot start TLS! $@\n") and return 0;
            }
            auth_login($pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            auth($user, $pass, $pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            mail($user, $pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            to(\@to, $pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            start_data($pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            my $filename = "file_name";
            my $dir = "/path/to/dir";
            my @is_ok = &read_file_send($dir, $filename, $pid);
            my $no_error = $is_ok[0];
            my $error_text = $is_ok[1];
            if (!$no_error) {
                &debug(3, $pid, $error_text);
                $is_ok[1] = "System error!";
                return (0, $smtp_error);
            }
            end_data($pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            quit($pid) or &debug(3, $pid, $smtp_error) and return (0, $smtp_error);
            close($socket);
            print "socket closed\n";
            return (1, "");
        }
    }
}

sub read_file_send {
    my ($dir, $filename, $pid) = @_;
    my $buffer;
    my $buffer_size = 1024*16;
    if (-d $dir ) {
        open (FILE,"$dir/$filename"); 
        binmode(FILE);
        &debug(3, $pid, "Sending data");
        while( sysread(FILE, $buffer , $buffer_size) ) {
            print $socket $buffer;
            usleep(100000);
        }
        print "....................OK\n";
        close (FILE);
        return (1, "");
    } else { 
        return (0, my $error = "Couldn't found directory");
    }
}
sub greeting {
    my ($socks_name, $pid) = @_;
    my $greet = "EHLO $socks_name.domain.com\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $greet") }
    print $socket $greet;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 250) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}
sub starttls {
    my $pid = shift;
    my $tls = "STARTTLS\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $tls") }
    print $socket $tls;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 220) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}

sub auth_login {
    my $pid = shift;
    my $auth = "AUTH LOGIN\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $auth") }
    print $socket $auth;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 334) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}

sub auth {
    my ($user, $pass, $pid) = @_;
    $user = encode_base64($user);
    $pass = encode_base64($pass);
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $user") }
    print $socket $user;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 334) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $pass") }
    print $socket $pass;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 235) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}

sub mail {
    my ($mail, $pid) = @_;
    $mail = "MAIL FROM:<$mail>\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $mail") }
    print $socket $mail;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 250) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}

sub to {
    my ($to, $pid) = @_;
    my @to = @{$to};
    foreach my $to (@to) {
    $to = "RCPT TO:<$to>\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $to") }
    print $socket $to;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 250) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    }
    return 1;
}

sub start_data {
    my $pid = shift;
    my $start = "DATA\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $start") }
    print $socket $start;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 354) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}

sub end_data {
    my $pid = shift;
    my $end = "\r\n.\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: .\n") }
    print $socket $end;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 250) { print $socket "QUIT\r\n" and return }
    return 1;
}

sub quit {
    my $pid = shift;
    my $quit = "QUIT\r\n";
    if ($debug_smtp eq 1) { &debug(3, $pid, "-->>: $quit") }
    print $socket $quit;
    if (data_read($pid) ne 221) { return }
    return 1;
}

sub data_read {
    my $pid = shift;
    my ($receive, $code, $reply, $end_time);
    my $buffer_size = 1024*16;
    my ($index, $end) = 0;
    undef $smtp_error;
    my $start_time = gettimeofday;
    usleep(200000);
    do {
        sysread($socket, $receive, $buffer_size);
        $end_time = gettimeofday;
        if ( int($end_time-$start_time) > 10 ) { $end = 1 }
    } until ( defined $receive or $end);
    if ( defined $receive and length $receive) {
        if ($debug_smtp eq 1) {
            my @lines = split /^/m, $receive;
            foreach my $line (@lines) {
                 &debug(3, $pid, "<<--: $line");
                 if ($index eq $#lines) { $code = $line }
                 $index++;
            }
        }
        $reply = substr($code, 0, 3);
        $smtp_error = $receive;
    } else {
        $smtp_error = "No response from server\n";
        $reply = '000';
    }
    return $reply;
}
```